Как выбрать нужный Converter в XAML, в зависимости от значения свойства во ViewModel?
У меня в приложении есть таблица цен, значения которой фактически представляют собой тип long, но для отображения в UI, необходимо делить эти значения на 100 с помощью конвертера:
class PenniesToRubleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int multiplier = 100;
        
        return (double) Math.Round(System.Convert.ToDouble(value), 0) / multiplier;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int multiplier = 100;
       
        try
        {
            var newValue = (value ?? 0f).ToString().Replace(".", ",");
            return System.Convert.ToSingle(newValue) * multiplier;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}

Код XAML из View, описывающий применение конвертера к конкретной колонке с ценами:
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=OrderMaxPrice, Converter={StaticResource penniesToRubleConverter}}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="0.5*">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <Label Foreground="{DynamicResource White}" Content="Макс. ордер"/>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

В чем суть проблемы:
В приложение добавилась поддержка валюты USD, значения которой имеют другую разрядность (тот же long, но на порядок больше - до десятых долей центов), и конвертер PenniesToRubleConverter не подходит для конвертации в подходящий для View формат. Делить теперь нужно на 1000.
Пробовал подставить ConverterParameter, но это не работает. Первая проблема этого подхода - ConverterParameter не принимает Binding в качестве параметра, и я не могу использовать выбранную валюту во ViewModel для передачи в конвертер.
Может есть способ назначать сам конвертер в зависимости от выбранной валюты во ViewModel? Например, если валюта окна - USD, то использовать CentsToDollarConverter, с делением на 1000, а если RUB - использовать существующий PenniesToRubleConverter?
Либо может есть другой способ обойти ограничение на привязку Binding к ConverterParameter?

Если параметров несколько, то используйте IMultiValueConverter, передавая тем самым все нужные параметры. А вообще, как по мне, у вас проблема в архитектуре, ибо вы должны 1. Хранить валюту не как long, а как, например, double, ибо сумма обычно имеет еще и "копейки", да и вы вон потом делаете конвертацию эту в конверторе. 2. У вас скорей всего должен быть полноценный объект "валюта", который имеет в себе все необходимое, включая тип, курс, значение, и так далее, ну и уже этот объект передавать в конвертор. Ну и 3. Laber использовать в WPF не лучшая идея, замените на TextBlock.

@EvgeniyZ Тогда уж decimal )   Раз уж валюты. Может double и хватит, но смотря какая валюта.

Да, проблема имеет именно архитектурные корни, но переделывать всю бизнес-логику с long на double не целесообразно. Все данные получаются через api нескольких сервисов, вся архитектура стоит на том, что на уровне логики мы работает с данными напрямую, как их получаем - в long.
Читал примеры про IMultiValueConverter - честно, так и не понял пока, как это реализуется. Сейчас мы в мой конвертер PenniesToRubleConverter передаем не валюту, а именно цену. Что мы будем передавать в IMultiValueConverter?

Про хранение цен. В long они хранятся итак с учётом копеек. Например мы получаем цену (в рублях) 101, это фактически 1 рубль, 01 копейка. В случае с валютой - 1 доллар 01 цент = 1010. Для этого мне и нужно решить вопрос с конвертацией, без вмешательства в бизнес-логику или ViewModel

Очень странный способ хранения значений, но да ладно... "Что мы будем передавать" - вы ведь в вопросе про это написали "валюта окна - USD", вот передавайте long и эту самую "валюту окна из VM, на основе этих данных уже и делайте нужные конвертации. Ну а про то как использовать, там ведь все элементарно, ну и есть даже в документации пример использования. Для красоты, можно использовать еще MarkupExtension.

Кажется, вы не совсем понимаете суть поблемы. Я и так передаю в конвертер цену

Но как мне дать конвертеру понять, что я передаю ему не рубли, как обычно, а USD, чтобы в зависимости от типа передаваемой валюты делить внутри конвертера цену не на 100, а на 1000?

В ConverterParameter мне нужно передавать либо "USD", либо "RUB", но я не могу захардкодить это просто в значение вот так:

Нужен некий Binding к свойству из ViewModel, потому что выбранная валюта задается событием во ViewModel. В то же время в ConverterParameter нельзя присвоить Binding...
Вы меня слышите или нет? Я вам говорю про мульти конвертор с мульти привязкой, а вы мне про параметр конвертора опять... Еще раз повторю, создайте IMultiValueConverter, который будет принимать long и string (если у вас USD это строка), там делайте нужные вычисления на основе этих данных, а в XAML используйте MultiBinding, через которое будет идти привязка к нужным значениям из нужных VM.

Я вас услышал. Выше писал, что читая про Multibinding не понял, как его реализовать на моём примере. Могли бы вы помочь, написав пример на основе моего кода Xaml?

Нашёл решение, которое может подойти в некоторых случаях лучше, чем MultiBinding и IMultiValueConverter (Спасибо @EvgeniyZ за помощь в поиске информации по вопросу).
Я решил проблему через proxy-объект, выступающий в качестве DataContext.
В VM я создал два свойства bool RubMode и bool UsdMode, сделал в XAML по две копии всех колонок, и отображаю их в зависимости от того, какая валюта задана в VM.
<DataGridTextColumn Visibility="{Binding Data.RubMode, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisible}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" Binding="{Binding Path=MinPrice, Converter={StaticResource penniesToRubleConverter}}">
<DataGridTextColumn Visibility="{Binding Data.UsdMode, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisible}, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" Binding="{Binding Path=MinPrice, Converter={StaticResource centsToDollarsConverter}}"> 

В моей задаче никак не избежать нарушения принципа DRY. Либо мы сильно раздуваем разметку, описывая Multibinding, и одинакового кода у нас добавляется больше в 7-10 местах, и при описании конвертера нужно очень серьезно поработать над обратной конвертацией, т.к. в методе ConvertBack конвертера мы принимаем на входе один объект, который на входе не может хранить данные о валюте, только её "сконвертированное" значение.
Можно, конечно, распарсить string-представление числа 741.012, чтобы понять, что это USD цена, но когда число будет 741.00, начнутся проблемы. К тому же точность у USD и EUR валют одинаковая.
Минус моего решения говорит сам за себя - на деле у нас две копии колонок, но в данном конкретном примере я его считаю несущественным, можно отрефакторить при наличии времени и желания (вплоть до изменения используемой визуальной технологии вместо XAML).


Это плохое решение, ибо вы на каждую валюту дублируете код. 2. Я вам показал как привязать 2 и более свойства, не более. Имея это на руках, вы могли написать все, что угодно, не дублируя код, а саму разметку вы могли сократить до простого Value = "{Binding ..., Converter = conv:CurrencyConverter ..., Currency = ... }" (правда там придется повозиться с привязками). Но проще неподходящее решение проигнорировать и пойти дальше, чем прокоментировать и найти оптимальное решение (которого кстати изначально не было).


Касательно "дублей" я вам изначально сказал, что у вас хреновая структура, у вас должен быть класс, который содержит в себе название валюты, ее "множители", описание, и все остальные значения, которые нужны, тогда весь ваш код превратится в условное value.Money * value.Currency.Multiple;, но вы переписывать проект отказываетесь, теперь вот мучаетесь с DRY... Чтож, это печально) В любом случае, мне кажется этот костыль намного хуже правильной привязки, ибо вы раздуваете еще код совершенно лишними свойствами. С таким успехом вон, триггеры можете попробовать тогда уж...
